# VBA Code to change a particular word in every slides of a Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which works well to change a particular word for another in one specific slide. I would like to know if there is a solution so that word is replaced by another one but in every slides, not 1 specifically. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub pres2()

    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    Dim myPres As Object
    Set myPres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\PRESVBA\Présentation2.pptx")

    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide 
    Set sld = myPres.Slides(3) '<- this is the only slide where change occurs
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape 

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Montant", "Amount")
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

This works well but only changes the word "Montant" to "Amount" in slide 3 and not in every slides like I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated code

```
Sub pres2()

    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    Dim myPres As Object
    Set myPres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\PRESVBA\Présentation2.pptx")

    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape

    For Each sld In myPres.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Montant", "Amount")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Please mark as answer if it resolves

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all of your slides using the following:

```
Dim sld As Slide   
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
     <individual slide code goes here>    
Next sld
```

You can substitute `ActivePresentation` with your specified presentation object.

More information on the `slides` object can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I seem to be getting a 424 error object required in one of these lines :

    `For Each sld In Présentation2.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes`

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to implement that solution in my code

Comment: Replace `<individual slide code goes here>` with your loop (`For Each shp In sld.Shapes` ... `Next Shp`)

Comment: When I do that I get an Error 424 Object required